# Race condition in Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, race-condition, parallel.foreach

Is there a possible race condition in below code?

```
public void Process(List<SomeObject> list)
{
    SomeDataOutput objData=null;
    ConcurrentBag<SomeDataOutput> cbOutput = new ConcurrentBag<SomeDataOutput>();
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions(){MaxDegreeOfParallelism=4};
    Parallel.ForEach(list, po, (objInput) =>
    {
        objData = GetOutputData(objInput);//THIS LINE IS THE ONE I AM UNSURE OF. CAN objData GET OVERWRITTEN BY MULTIPLE PARALLEL THREADS?
        cbOutput.Add(objData);
    });
}
```

Comment: That will depend on how you implement `GetOutputData`, since that's the method that allocates or reuses existing objects. The fact that `objData` is declared outside the `ForEach` does not, in itself, mean that there is a risk of one thread reading another thread's object.

Comment: @PaulHicks: You've described the problem pretty accurately, apart from denying that it is a problem.  The fact that `objData` is declared outside the lambda means that it is a capture, and all instances of the lambda will share a single variable.  So yes, there certainly is a risk of one thread reading another thread's object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a possible race condition. Two threads might interleave the statements in the loop body as follows:

```
Thread #1                             Thread #2
==================================    ==================================
objData = GetOutputData(objInput);
                                      objData = GetOutputData(objInput);
cbOutput.Add(objData);
                                      cbOutput.Add(objData);
```

Because `objData` is declared outside the loop, the two threads share the same variable. As a result, Thread #2 overwrites the `objData` reference set by Thread #1, and Thread #2's `objData` gets added to `cbOutput` twice.

To prevent `objData` from being shared by multiple threads, make it a local variable:

```
SomeDataOutput objData = GetOutputData(objInput);
cbOutput.Add(objData);
```

Or you can get rid of the variable altogether:

```
cbOutput.Add(GetOutputData(objInput));
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. That was my exact doubt as well. Just for understanding - if I were to change this to Parallel.ForEach(list,po,(objInput) => {cbOutput.Add(GetOutputData(objInput))}); 
would it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, that fixes the problem too. It's equivalent to my second suggestion.

Comment: Thanks - just saw that...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

(Edited to remove incorrect and distracting information)

And as the other answer says, you can do this: (remaining bits of this answer predate my corrections (thanks to Ben Voight)).

```
public void Process(List<SomeObject> list)
{
    ConcurrentBag<SomeDataOutput> cbOutput = new ConcurrentBag<SomeDataOutput>();
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions(){MaxDegreeOfParallelism=4};
    Parallel.ForEach(list, po, (objInput) =>
    {
        cbOutput.Add(GetOutputData(objInput));
    });
}
```

And that obviously has no risk of overwriting objects or memory.

Comment: No, it's not exactly equivalent.

Comment: Yes, it is beginning to confuse me again.. I was answering that there was a race condition, then I tested it and I couldn't create it, and then I wrote this answer. Looks like I'll need to reproduce it harder :)

Comment: Unfortunately, testing can't prove the absence of a race condition.

Comment: Thanks Ben, Paul - very useful discussion.